# Add folder parameter to Rails simple form upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, simple-form, cloudinary

In my rails app, I use Carrierwave to upload files to Cloudinary. I also use Simple form to render forms in views. I am trying to upload my files to specific folders in cloudinary.

In the uploader.rb file, this works well

```
def public_id
  return "my_folder/" + model.full_name
end
```

But what I want is to specify the folder parameter in the views using simple form. So i tried something like this,

```
 <%= f.input :resume, :folder => "talents/", :public_id => "my_name" %>
```

The files get uploaded to Cloudinary but not the folder. Is it possible to pass the folder parameter successfully to simple form in the views?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the folder as part of the public_id:

```
<%= f.input :resume, :public_id => "talents/my_name" %>
```

In cloudinary a folder is part of the public_id.
Please let me know if that helps,